# I'm trying to parse past earnings data in tradingview pine code

Tags: parsing, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to parse past earnings data in tradingview pine code, but I don't think there's a way to do this? Please help me if there is a possible solution. Thanks.

Here's a working private script with the extra code that does not work. lol.

https://www.tradingview.com/script/KtqD1dXz-Time-it/

```
ea = dayofweek(time('D')) == earnings.future_period_end_time
```